# Handling value state with multiple Formik forms on one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am building a page using React and Formik. On my form page, I have three Formik forms that are conditionally rendered using a switch statement. I am doing it this way because each form's data need to be sent to their own api endpoint so I'm keeping them logically separated. When the first form is submitted, it cycles to the next. I am having an issue where when accessing the value prop in the second Formik form, it displays the values from the first. It appears as though Formik by default isn't handling the data separation when multiple Formik's exist, despite them existing in different return statements.

My switch statement is something like this:

```
switch(currentform) {
    case 'form1':
        return (
            <Formik
                initialValues={form1Values}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                    let form1= JSON.stringify(values, null, 2);
                    console.log(form1)
                 }}
                 >
                {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
                    <Form className='form-container'>
                    
                 </Form>
                 )}
                </Formik>

        )
     case 'form2':
        return (
            <Formik
                initialValues={form2Values}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                    let form2= JSON.stringify(values, null, 2);
                    console.log(form2)
                 }}
                 >
                {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
                    <Form className='form-container'>
                    
                 </Form>
                 )}
                </Formik>

        )
}
```

When submitting `form1`, the `console.log(form1)` displays the correct data. After submitting `form2`, the `console.log(form2)` returns the same data as `form1`. I've tried renaming the `values` prop in each `onSubmit` but that doesn't seem to change the behavior. Can someone help to confirm if my implementation is flawed or if there is a better way to configure this? Thanks to anyone who reads this!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good method. You need to write a separate component outside the default fn for each form.

For Example,

import { Formik } from 'formik';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

```
export const ProductForm = () => {
   const renderForms = (form) => {
    switch (form) {
     case 0:
                    return <Form1 } />
                  case 1:
                    return <Form2 } />
                  case 2:
                    return <Form3 />
                  case 3:
                    return <Form4} />
            
                  default:
                    return ""
                }
              }
    
    return {renderForms()}
            
            }
           
    const Form1 = ({}) =>{
    return ( <Formik
    initialValues={form1Values}
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {}>
    {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
    <Form className='form-container'>
    </Form>)}
     </Formik>)}
```